# cannot control programmatically created UILabel, UIPicker and UINavigation

Tags: swift

This is from a tutorial and all is working except this strange UI behavior. The "Sec" label is good but as you can see the "Min" label is too far to the left.

Also as you can see the top layout and bottom layout are red but the red color is no where in the swift file or Inspector.

First of all I need some clarification. UI was done all programmatically, but there are elements listed in the Xcode Document Outline tree. In addition, IBOutlets with connections exist in the Swift file yet there is no xib or UI elements on the storyboard.

So please tell me, does Xcode automatically place those elements in the Document Outline and IBOutlets in the swift file if elements are done programmatically?

[image]

```
var myTimer = NSTimer()
var inMinute: Int = 0
var inSecond: Int = 0
var myTime: Int = 0
var inputedTime: Int = 0

var player : AVAudioPlayer! = nil
var playing = NSTimer()
var startPoint = 0.0

@IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var start_stop_Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    start_stop_Button.layer.cornerRadius = start_stop_Button.bounds.size.height //45
    start_stop_Button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    pauseButton.layer.cornerRadius = pauseButton.bounds.size.height
    pauseButton.layer.opacity = 0.4
    pauseButton.enabled = false

    timePicker.layer.opacity = 1.0
    minLabel.layer.opacity = 1.0
    secLabel.layer.opacity = 1.0
    countLabel.layer.opacity = 0.0

    countLabel.text = "00:00"

}




@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender.titleLabel?.text as String! {
    case "Start":
        inMinute = timePicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        inSecond = timePicker.selectedRowInComponent(1)
        inputedTime = inMinute * 60 + inSecond    // total time in seconds.

        myTime = inputedTime

        if myTime != 0 {

            timer(1)

            timePicker.layer.opacity = 0.0
            minLabel.layer.opacity = 0.0
            secLabel.layer.opacity = 0.0
            countLabel.layer.opacity = 1.0

            start_stop_Button.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            start_stop_Button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            pauseButton.layer.opacity = 1
            pauseButton.enabled = true

        }

        break

    case "Cancel":
        timer(0)

        break

    case "Pause":
        timer(2)
        pauseButton.setTitle("Resume", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        break

    case "Resume":
        timer(1)
        pauseButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        break

    default: break
    }


}


func timer(state:Int){

    switch state {
    case 0:
        myTimer.invalidate()
        progressBar.progress = 1.0
        player.stop()

        timePicker.selectRow(0,inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        timePicker.selectRow(0,inComponent: 1, animated: true)

        timePicker.layer.opacity = 1.0
        minLabel.layer.opacity = 1.0
        secLabel.layer.opacity = 1.0
        countLabel.layer.opacity = 0.0

        countLabel.text = "00:00"

        start_stop_Button.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        start_stop_Button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        if pauseButton.titleLabel?.text as String! == "Resume" {
            pauseButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        pauseButton.layer.opacity = 0.4
        pauseButton.enabled = false

        break

    case 1:
        countLabel.text = String(format:"%02d:%02d", myTime/60, myTime%60)
        myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("countDown"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        break

    case 2:
        myTimer.invalidate()
        break

    default:break

    }

}

func playAlarm() {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sound/saigon", ofType:"wav")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)

    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()
    player.numberOfLoops = -1 // new code
    print(player.duration)
    playing = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("playerDidFinishPlaying"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func playerDidFinishPlaying() {

    startPoint = startPoint+1

    if player.duration - startPoint <= 0 {
        timer(0)
        playing.invalidate()
        startPoint = 0
    }
}


func countDown(){
    myTime = myTime - 1

    countLabel.text = String(format:"%02d:%02d", myTime/60, myTime%60)

    progressBar.progress = progressBar.progress - 1.0/Float(inputedTime)
    print("\(myTime)")

    if myTime == 0 {
        myTimer.invalidate()
        progressBar.progress = 0

        pauseButton.layer.opacity = 0.4
        pauseButton.enabled = false

        playAlarm()
    }

}
```

Comment: You say the controls were created programmatically, but what you're showing appears to be a storyboard and code for controls that were created with Interface Builder. You typically set the constraints that define their positioning there. — Otherwise, perhaps you need to clarify your question.

Comment: You are exactly right Elmer!!! It does APPEAR to be done via storyboard. But I can assure you it's not lol This is why this is so strange. I know what you're thinking. That I'm nuts. But let me reassure you. There is NOTHING on the VC. It's blank. This is the first time I have seen this phenomenon in Xcode.

Comment: Where in your code do you think controls are being created programmatically? I don't see any controls being created in the code you posted.

Comment: it's ok. I just created everything from scratch for safety. I will delete this question. Thanks for your help anyway Elmer.